# grouping variables into a system in C?

Tags: c, variables

Within C, say I have a number of variables, floats, integers etc, is there a way that I can group them all into one object, lets call it a system, and then create N copies of such an object.

Further, is there a way to assign to each copy of the system a particular value of a variable T such that each system has a different but predetermined T?

I am very new to C programming so don't quite know where to start, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29

Comment: You would probably find going completely though a C language guide book (I found the [K&R](http://www.amazon.com/The-Programming-Language-Brian-Kernighan/dp/0131103628) to be a rather accessible book) to be helpful. There is far too much in the C programming language to roseately go through it feature by feature as a question by question.

Comment: recommended reading: **[Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)**

Comment: Thank you both very much for your advice :). I was specifically interested in grouping **different** data types into one package and then assigning a parameter to each. My question was specifically about the collecting and the assignation part.  Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty way to do it:

```
typedef unsigned int t_t;

struct your_thing {
    int a;
    float b;
    char z[20];

    t_t t;
};

struct your_thing copy_thing(struct your_thing thing) {
    static t_t counter = 0;
    thing.t = counter++;
    return thing;
}
```

## Example:

```
struct your_thing a = { ... };
a = copy_thing(a); // needed to initialize a.t
struct your_thing b = copy_thing(a);
```

`b.t` is now different than `a.t`, and as long as all copies of the struct are made with `copy_thing()` they will never collide.

This is not a very good way of doing this, though, since the `static` variable is global and not thread safe. I can't see why you would want to do this. What you probably have here is the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will need to go away and think about it and understand what you have written, is there significance to "t_t" ? As for my purpose, I am trying to implement a replica exchange experiment, many thanks :)

Comment: `t_t` is just a typedef name. It's common in C to use the `_t` suffix to indicate a type (e.g. `size_t`, `uint32_t`, `pid_t`, ...). You gave your variable the name `t`, so I used `t_t` to represent the type of `t`.

Comment: Can the struct command hold arrays as well as discrete variables?

Comment: @AngusTheMan struct isn't exactly a command... I think you'll need to sit down and learn C before you can understand any answer to this question. The folk who commented on your question have suggested a couple ways to get started.

Comment: yes, the `struct` can hold arrays of fixed size.  most of the time programmers put a **pointer** to an array in a C structure and allocate the space for the array somewhere else.  but **do** curl up with Kernigan&Ritchie a bit and learn the basics about arrays, pointers, structs, unions, and typedef in C.  all of your questions will be answered.